# Prove $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x\mathrm{sin}(x) \;\mathrm{d}x \leq \frac{\pi^{2}}{8}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

An answer to this question is:

Since $x\mathrm{sin}x \leq x$, by the comparison property...
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x\mathrm{sin}(x) \;\mathrm{d}x &\leq \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x \;\mathrm{d}x\\
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x\mathrm{sin}(x) \;\mathrm{d}x &\leq \frac{\pi^{2}}{8}
\end{align}

Hence proved.

But what I am really having trouble understanding is how do you recognize, in this case, that the integral to compare is $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x \;\mathrm{d}x$? I understand that the reason this integral was chosen was because it equals $\frac{\pi^{2}}{8}$; In a more general case, however, how does one recognize what would be a good comparison to make? There's also the issue of somehow recognizing, and proving that $x\mathrm{sin}(x)
 \leq x$. Is this something that just comes with practice to somehow apply known patterns? I can't imagine that simple pattern recognition is the solution in all scenarios...

Are there any tricks, or tactics that you can recommend to help the process of narrowing down the possibilities for these types of questions in math? They seem to pop up rather often.

Comment: The questions which are best suited to the Q&A format of Math SE are those which are narrowly focused and which admit objectively correct answers.  This question seems more designed to provoke discussion, and strikes me as off-topic.  What would a good answer to this question even look like?

Comment: Somewhat unfortunately, this often just comes with experience. As you progress in analysis you'll start to recognize some of the most standard estimates; $|\sin(x)|\leq|x|$ is one of the more common ones that you'll see. Keep working problems, and eventually you'll have enough tricks up your sleeve that you'll be able to pull out the correct one to use.

Answer (score 2):

> In a more general case, however, how does one recognize what would be
> a good comparison to make?

There is no general rule. The answer to your question is "with experience".

Comment: I see. That's rather unfortunate. Are there any tricks, or tactics that you can recommend which help the process of narrowing down the possibilities?

Comment: @Kalcifer The fact that mathematics cannot be neatly packaged into a few easy to use paint-by-numbers exercise is quite the opposite of "unfortunate" if you ask me. It's what makes it beautiful and worthwhile. If mathematics didn't demand a spark of creativity to do well, then we'd relegate it to computers. As for tricks and tactics, the best tactic is to do a lot of exercises, that's the only way to see what works best for you. For example, to me, drawing the plots of the two functions works very well, but someone else would find them completely useless.